# Yield in Python

Tags: python

Something I don't understand happens when I try to convert a iterator returned by `yield` to list.

For Example1:

```
def test(n):
    params = dict()
    for i in range(n):
        params[i] = i
        yield params

for item in test(10):
    print(item)
```

Everything of outputs is ok:

```
{0: 0}
{0: 0, 1: 1}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
...
...
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
```

But with example2:

```
~ # same as above

def test(n):
    params = dict()
    for i in range(n):
        params[i] = i
        yield params

test_lst = list(test(10))  # change here
for item in test_lst:      # ~
    print(item)
```

Something I did not expect happened:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
...
...
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}
```

So can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem can be summarize to the following:

Why does `print` give me the increasing steps of the object, while `list` gives me all the endpoints?

The answer if **because your test_lst contains pointers to the same object and this one was updated over time** while print showed your a snapshot of the object.

If you want the intermediate steps, you need to make a copy:

```
[i.copy() for i in test(4)]
```

output:

```
[{0: 0},
 {0: 0, 1: 1},
 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2},
 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}]
```

###### pointer to the same object:

```
[i for i in test(4)]
```

```
[{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}]
```

Another way to understand the issue. Try to modify (not replace) one of the elements in the list:

```
>>> test_lst[0][0] = 'abc'
[{0: 'abc', 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 {0: 'abc', 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 {0: 'abc', 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9},
 {0: 'abc', 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `list` function on your iterator, it iterates over the entire collection until it's exhausted. Thus you immediately receive all of the possible values.

Fortunately your generator is not infinite :)

Comment: No the question is why do print and list give different output. The fact that the generator is finite is a pre-requisite of the code, not a source of the issue.

Comment: @mozway In both ways the person iterates over the result and prints an element each iteration.
The question is not about printing but about the shape of the elements in the collection after casting to a `list`.

Comment: @mozway your answer is interesting, but I genuinely think that the question was about generator behavior.

Comment: I think the question is why first creating a list "yields" (pun intended) a different result than when directly iterating using only a `for` loop. And you're both right, both answers are correct, in my opinion, although with different wordings. Tip for EgorLu: I think this answer is a bit short and difficult to understand for anyone that's not yet familiar with the topics (so anybody that would ask the above question). Some more explanation and/or an example might improve the answer.

Comment: I feel *both* answers are useful in that they explain the issue from different perspectives / levels of detail.  Upvote to both.

Comment: I think I figure out the issue, that is just because all the dict of `params` yielded by `generator` are the same object reference in the second example. Therefore, all changes will point to the object.